# MediaPlayer giving error (262,0)

Tags: android, button, audio

I am a very beginner and trying to make my very first applications with buttons which plays sounds when pressed... A soundboard, I think.

> E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
>
> E/MediaPlayer: Error (262,0)

When I tap the button second time:

> E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

These are the errors I get with this simple code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer m1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.s1);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m1.start();
        }
    });}
```

"s1.mp3" is in raw folder, is about 3-4 seconds long, I think it's not the problem...
I don't understand what I am doing wrong - an online tutorial taught me all these, there was a similar code...
Please help me, as I said, I am a beginner developer so I need help...
Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer m1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.s1);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m1.start();
        }
    });}
 }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.antiriad7.zviadi.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/l1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S1"
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:text="S2"
        android:id="@+id/s2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S3"
        android:id="@+id/s3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
    android:id="@+id/l2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S4"
        android:id="@+id/s4"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:text="S5"
        android:id="@+id/s5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S6"
        android:id="@+id/s6"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/l2"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/l3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S7"
        android:id="@+id/s7"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:text="S8"
        android:id="@+id/s8"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S9"
        android:id="@+id/s9"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/l3"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/l4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S10"
        android:id="@+id/s10"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:text="S11"
        android:id="@+id/s11"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="S12"
        android:id="@+id/s12"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your mp3 song is playing or not when button click??

Comment: No, it doesn't play...

Comment: see my Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

When the MediaPlayer starts playing a music, it checks if there is a SubtitleController and shows this message if it's not set. It doesn't seem to care about if the source you want to play is a music or video. Not sure why he did that.

**Don't care about this "Exception".**

To remove this exception follow this step :

1. Right click on track(Your raw folder .mp3 file)
2. then select Property
3. select Details
4. then insert song text(title) on subtitle
5. Done

**Updated**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Mediaplayer m1; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
m1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.s1);
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        m1.start();
    }
});}
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: I cannot edit Subtitle... Maybe I should do something from android studio itself? Will that fix & make button play sound?

Comment: Don't care about this exception.have you update your code according to my answer??

Comment: And declare your mediaplayer variable globally

Comment: I've updated but same. What do you mean in 'globally'?

Comment: just copy & past my updated answer in your mainactivity and add one song in raw folder....it is work definately

Comment: Globally means if you want to use ur mediaplayer variable  more time in ur activity.

Comment: E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0

Comment: This is what I get when I press it

Comment: first tell me have you use my updated code in ur activity??

Comment: song is playing or not?.....It is works when i use this code and it is simple code to play song on button click

Comment: Added xml. But it's joint with the java code. I think you'll understand.

Comment: i see ur xml file and it's good......In each button s1 to s12 u have add song to play from raw folder??....first i suggest test one button to play song.

Comment: I am doing test on one button. Each button should play different sounds. I haven't even added OnClickListeners for them. I am testing for one S1 button. And it doesn't work. :(

Comment: I've not changed anything but now I get (262,0) error instead of (38,0)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your XML just like it is and then change your MainActivity code to exactly this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer m1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        m1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.s1);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m1.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then do a Build --> Clean Project in Android Studio, and then run it. Does it work? What's the error?

Comment: I get E/MediaPlayer: error (262, 0) when I click at first time. The app itself on phone doesn't crash but doesn't play sound.